# .slideToggle() ONLY items that are collapsed

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

So, I've done a lot of research trying to find this, but can't seem to find something that works.

I have multiple divs on a page using .slidetoggle(); to display more content in a child div. What I would like to do is add an "expand all" button that would only expand those who are closed, while leaving the rest alone. Currently, the expand all works, but only if all of the items are collapsed. Otherwise it basically just switches, so if a user opens one item, then decides later they just want to view all, it will open those that are closed, but close the one that is already open. I know there's gotta be an easy way to work around this but I'm relatively new to both jQuery and javascript.

Here's my current code- my apologies if it is sloppy, I'm a beginner!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".question1").click(function(){
$("#answer1").slideToggle();
});
});

$(document).ready(function(){
$(".question2").click(function(){
$("#answer2").slideToggle();
});
});

$(document).ready(function(){
$(".question3").click(function(){
$("#answer3").slideToggle();
});
});

$(document).ready(function(){
$(".expandall").click(function(){
$(".answer").slideToggle();
});
});
```

And my html-

```
<button class="expandall">Expand All</button>
<div class="question">
<button class="question1"><b>This is a Question</b></button>
</div>

<div id="answer1" class="answer" style="display:none;">
This is an answer
</div></div>

<div class="question">
<button class="question2"><b>This is a Question</b></button>
</div>

<div id="answer2" class="answer" style="display:none;">
This is an answer
</div></div>

<div class="question">
<button href="#" class="question3"><b>This is a Question</b></button>
</div>

<div id="answer3" class="answer" style="display:none;">
This is an answer
</div></div>
```

Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".expandall").click(function(){
    $(".answer").slideToggle();
  });
});
```

into this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".expandall").click(function () {
    $(".answer:hidden").slideToggle();
  });
});
```

only answers that are currently hidden (collapsed) will toggle.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qc04secd/), and for reference: http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/

As a sidenote - it's not necessary that you wrap each `click()` event in a single `$(document).ready()` - one is sufficient. When jQuery is loaded, all `click()` events will be attached.

In addition, it's also possible to have a single statement for all `question` buttons instead of 3 separate `click()` events:

```
$(".question button").click(function () {
    $(this).parent(".question").next(".answer").slideToggle();
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/waqr13v0/) and as snippet (with the accidental second closing `</div>` tag from the `answers` removed):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".question button").click(function() {
    $(this).parent(".question").next(".answer").slideToggle();
  });
  $(".expandall").click(function() {
    $(".answer:hidden").slideToggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="expandall">Expand All</button>
<div class="question">
  <button class="question1"><b>This is a Question</b>
  </button>
</div>
<div id="answer1" class="answer" style="display:none;">This is an answer</div>
<div class="question">
  <button class="question2"><b>This is a Question</b>
  </button>
</div>
<div id="answer2" class="answer" style="display:none;">This is an answer</div>
<div class="question">
  <button href="#" class="question3"><b>This is a Question</b>
  </button>
</div>
<div id="answer3" class="answer" style="display:none;">This is an answer</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked like a charm :) and THANK YOU for the feedback on repeating the $(document).ready function and the repeating of the click functions. I knew there was a way to control only a child div of the parent so you could just use the one function but wasn't too sure on how to go about doing it.

Comment: @KiannaChauntis Glad I was able to help you :). If this answered your question, you can consider to accept this answer so the question will be marked as closed / solved. In case you don't know how this works and why, just check http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#answer-5235